# Ternary Operator second part not rendering React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

The Second part i.e sign up part is not rendering

The intention is to get the span being changed on click each tab i.e sign ,sign up and forget This is the main class and the form class is called in it.
The below code is the original code used to render in the screen

```
   class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   // this.setOptionSignIn = this.setOptionSignIn.bind(this);
   // this.setOptionSignUp = this.setOptionSignUp.bind(this);
   // this.setOptionForget = this.setOptionForget.bind(this);

   this.state = {
     option : 1    
   }
 }

setOptionSignIn = () => {
 this.setState(()=> {
   return {
     option : 1
   }
 })
}
setOptionSignUp = () => {
 this.setState(()=> {
   return {
     option : 2
   }
 })
}
setOptionForget = () => {
 this.setState(()=> {
   return {
     option : 3
   }
 })
}
render() {
 return (
     <div className="container">
     {
       console.log(this.state.option+"before and type is "+ typeof this.state.option)
     }
     <header className={
 `header-headings ${this.state.option === 1 ? 'sign-in' : this.state.option === 2 ? 'sign-up' : 'forgot'}`}>       
         <span>Sign in to your account</span>
         <span>Create an account</span>    
         <span>Reset your password</span>
     </header>   
     {
       console.log(this.state.option+"after and type is "+ typeof this.state.option)
     }
     <ul className="options">
     <li className={this.state.option === 1 ? 'active' : ''} onClick={this.setOptionSignIn}>Sign in</li>
     <li className={this.state.option === 2 ? 'active' : ''} onClick={this.setOptionSignUp}>Sign up</li>
     <li className={this.state.option === 3 ? 'active' : ''} onClick={this.setOptionForget}>Forget</li> 
     </ul>
     <Form optionState={this.state.option} />
     </div>
 )}
}
```

Comment: Try adding parentheses according to the logic you want, like: `this.state.option === 1 ? "sign-in": (this.state.option === 2 ? "sign-up" : "forgot")`

Comment: I tried but still its not taking the second condition when option is 2

Comment: can you do some logs of your state and tell us what it logs at different states? `console.log("state is and type is" , this.state.option , typeof this.state.option)`

Comment: the code is :  <div className="container">{
        console.log(this.state.option+"before and type is "+ typeof this.state.option)      }
      <header className={
  `header-headings ${this.state.option === 1 ? 'sign-in' : this.state.option === 2 ? 'sign-up' : 'forgot'}`}>       
          <span>Sign in to your account</span>
          <span>Create an account</span>    
          <span>Reset your password</span>
      </header>   {        console.log(this.state.option+"after and type is "+ typeof this.state.option)
      }

Comment: yeah open the console and tell us what those console.log logs for you? Also please keep code part in your question.

Comment: the console details are:  before and type is number
App.js:48 1after and type is number
App.js:40 2before and type is number
App.js:48 2after and type is number
App.js:40 3before and type is number
App.js:48 3after and type is number

Comment: @AtinSingh the code has been updated and the console details mentioned in previous comment

Comment: It should work as intended. Can you create a code sandbox repo for us to debug?

Comment: @AtinSingh please guide for the same

Comment: Add the full component code and i'll try to create a code sandbox. Also you said The intention is to get the span being changed on click each tab i.e sign ,sign up and forget. But all you are doing is changing the class of header. Those span would appear all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To switch the span based on the option insert the condition in span.

```
 <span>{this.state.option === 1 ? 'Sign in to your account' : this.state.option === 2 ? 'Create an account' : 'Reset your password'}</span>
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

The `ternary` condition you are using above is correct. The problem may be related to the state which is not properly updated.

The state has to be updated using `this.setState()` method and not by changing the state properties directly on the `this.state` object.

Please check out the code below:

**SignIn method:**

```js
setOptionSignIn() {
   this.setState({
     option: 1
   });
}
```

**SignUp method**

```js
setOptionSignUp() {
   this.setState({
      option: 2
   });
}
```

**ForgetPassword method:**

```js
setOptionForget() {
   this.setState({
      option: 0
   });
}
```